# How to rewire a dependency of a specific module?

Tags: webpack

My webpack project uses module "apple" that has a dependency "seed". I want to overwrite the "seed" dependency to use my script instead.

I have read https://webpack.github.io/docs/shimming-modules.html. The latter only advises how to declare a local variables that imports a dependency; it does not say how to rewire a dependency.

One way to do it is to add an alias:

```
'seed$': './my-seed.js'
```

However, using this approach overwrites "seed" dependency for the entire project, which can cause undesired results.

Comment: In good old RequireJS, this was trivial with the `map` configuration; I am making the transition to Webpack and I am surprised this isn't equally trivial (or even possible at all?). Maybe the [rewire-webpack plugin](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire-webpack) could help though.